# How making this border half transparent (striped)?

Tags: css

Im surf and see this pic, interested border. How making border like on img, if responsive it need use mask? Because i want get transparent figure where it is black, how is possible?

(sorry my eng)

[image: striped border]

---

im used clip-path but it is not given need result

this is what I got - [codepen](https://codepen.io/grdnk/pen/Poyvdez)

```css
.section {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.section.border {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.section.border::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  bottom: -25px;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="section border"></section>
  <section class="section"></section>
</main>
```

Comment: The first thing to do when trying to figure out how a web design was accomplished is to view the source code. This is much easier on a desktop browser; just right-click on the element and select "Inspect" to view the markup in Developer Tools

Comment: @TimR Unfortunately, this just concept image...

Comment: I can't think of how to use CSS to create a "pill" border that would replicate this. However, I'm sure it could be done using a background image (that is 100% width) in a block between the sections.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community question upd...